# Training Needs Analysis Database in PhpMyAdmin - Having difficulty storing user specific radio answers in my database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a novice with regards to programming but here goes. I am using PhpMyAdmin as part of an academic course but my knowledge is limited but I am a quick learner, although I have limited support from my University.

I am looking to create a simple Training Needs Analysis Database which only has to be a prototype. I have created my tables and made an attempt at the script though I am stuck. I want my page to display radio buttons for each question (which I have generically called Skills Question 1, 2, 3 etc for now) and insert the answers into my tnaanswers table.

I have looked up this site for support and attempted various suggestions although I am unable to get it to work. The syntax error I am getting is undefined post on line 40, which refers to the first post under the heading "Skills Question 1".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am aware that mysql is depreciated but I don't know enough about mysqli or pdo to change all of my script to match.

The columns of my tnaanswers table are as follows:

UserID - Primary Key of my users table, trying to unique identify who is logged on and insert this into my tnaanswers table.

TnaID - Primary Key of my tnaquestions table, used to identify the question and the associated support video.

TnaValue - Will be Y or N depending if the user selects yes or no on each radio.

I have used the action displaytnavideos.php as I hope to use this page to run a query to pull the Y values and display my video content for the videos the user has selected yes to.

My script is as follows:

```
<?php

    require_once("db_connection.php");

    session_start();

    //Select database
    $database = "com904";
    $db = mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$radioPost="INSERT INTO tnaanswers (UserID, TnaID, TnaValue)VALUES 
    (('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna1', '$_POST[Tna1]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna2', '$_POST[Tna2]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna3', '$_POST[Tna3]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna4', '$_POST[Tna4]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna5', '$_POST[Tna5]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna6', '$_POST[Tna6]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna7', '$_POST[Tna7]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna8', '$_POST[Tna8]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna9', '$_POST[Tna9]),
    ('$_POST[UserID]', 'Tna10', '$_POST[Tna10]));

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


?>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Do you require support with the following ICT skills? </title>
</head> 
<body>

        <h3>Skills question 1</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna1" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna1" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 2</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna2" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna2" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 3</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna3" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna3" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 4</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna4" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna4" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 5</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna5" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna5" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 6</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna6" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna6" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 7</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna7" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna7" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 8</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna8" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna8" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 9</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna9" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna9" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <h3>Skills question 10</h3>
        <form method="post" action="displayTnaVideos.php">
        <input type="radio" name="Tna10" value="Y"><label>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Tna10" value="N"><label>No</label><br/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="submit"> 


</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is your INSERT statement, which is using quotes incorrectly and is missing concatenations. Additionally, its missing a final double quote at the very end before the semicolon ;

When switching between plain text like "Tna1" and a php variable (which would be anything starting with a dollar sign $), you need to concatenate them. In this example I use a period . to do this, but there are other ways too, for example using curly braces {}

```
$radioPost="INSERT INTO tnaanswers (UserID, TnaID, TnaValue) VALUES 
    (
    ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', 'Tna1', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'),
    ('".$_POST['UserID']."', 'Tna1', '".$_POST['Tna1']."'),
    ('".$_POST['UserID']."', 'Tna2', '".$_POST['Tna2']."'),
    ('".$_POST['UserID']."', 'Tna3', '".$_POST['Tna3']."')
    )";
```